# JQuery read complex table structure

Tags: jquery, html-table

Actually I am working on NetSuite and I need some work related to JavaScript.

**I want to check if table td is empty then show other table td record.**

As in below Image. If table ID `related` with td class `single-related-product` is empty.

[image]

Then Show below record. i.e. td class `no-related-itemp` will show.

[image]

I have written below code. but it does not work.

```
$('document #related tr').each(function() {
   if ($(this).find('td:empty').length) $('td p.no-related-itemp').show();
});
```

Any Help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this)` and `find` to get class `no-related-itemp` inside `tr` like below and Check your condition with `length` like 0, 1 what ever suitable for your condition.

```
$('#related tr').each(function() {
   if ($(this).find('td:empty').length == 1) // Check your condition using >, == , < 
    $(this).find('p.no-related-itemp').show();
});
```

Comment: If I add just alert before if statement. Alert is not coming. mean does not read document #related tr.

Comment: No need  `document ` just use ID and be sure  id must be Unique.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with this line

if ($(this).find('td:empty').length) $('td p.no-related-itemp').show();

Just check the length > 0